# How to rewrite value of variable using useState?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, axios

I am using react and typescript. I have a function which gets users location. I need to save latitude and longitude using useState and then send it ot my end point, but when i am trying to console.log(latitude, longitude) i just have a blank. So what is correct way to solve my problem? And maybe there are some ways to optimize my code?

I tried that, but it doesn't work.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "preact/hooks";
import axios from "axios";

export function useSendLocation() {

  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState('')
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState('')

  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.")
    }
  }


  function showPosition(position: any) {
    setLatitude(position.coords.latitude)
    setLongitude(position.coords.longitude)
    console.log(longitude, latitude)
  }

  const [ip, setIP] = useState("");

  const getData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
    setIP(res.data.ip);
    if (res.data.ip === null || undefined) {
      alert('Can\'t get yout IP')
    }
  };

  const ipData: String = ip
  const latitudeData: String = latitude
  const longitudeData: String = longitude

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post('some/endpoint', {
      latitude: latitudeData,
      longitude: longitudeData,
      user_ip: ipData
    }).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
  })


  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    setInterval(getLocation, 5000)
  }, []);

}
```

Comment: Your variables haven't been set until the next render cycle. Try logging it where you're setting lattitudeData and longitudeData. Also add those vars to the dependency list so you only post when they have changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch request in regular intervals using the useEffect hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71300548/how-to-fetch-request-in-regular-intervals-using-the-useeffect-hook)

Comment: @AmyBlankenship it helped but now i am getting first log as blank and second with location. May be you know some way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

### Original problem

Try adding a `console.log()` for the longitude and latitude that is not inside any function or hook, this should log everytime the values change.

if that does not work, log what is returned by `navigator.geolocation` to make sure the data returned is defined

### Optimize

Ideally you should have 1 state for both the longitude and latitude

```js
 const [position, setPosition] = useState<{longitudeData: string, latitudeData: string}>({longitudeData: '', latitudeData: ''});

// ...

axios.post('some/endpoint', {
      ...position,
      user_ip: ipData
    }).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```